# Is it possible to use the required property in IE?

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, validation, html

I have code like this:

```
<input required>
```

In good browsers I can use jquery like this to add a class of error to the input:

```
$('input[required]').addClass('error');
```

It doesn't work in IE though. I will resort to this otherwise, but it's not as neat...

HTML:

```
<input data-required=true>
```

Javascript:

```
if( $('input').data('required') ) $('input').addClass('error');
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Will

EDIT:

Yea, I am using HTML5.

IE actually interprets this:

```
<input required>
```

as:

```
<input required="">
```

So it is possible to check that like this:

```
if( $('input').prop() == undefined )
```

But again, it's a bit of a messy way of doing things, especially considering that it is only IE that has the issue. This code works perfectly in all other browsers.

I am basically asking if there is a method of checking that is cross browser and tidy. I'm a bit of a perfectionist perhaps! ;)

Comment: It's invalid HTML. A valid HTML would look like this: `<input required="required" />`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `<input required>` is definitely valid HTML.

Comment: That depends heavily on your doctype. [HTML5 allows it](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#required)

Comment: Strange, the validator (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) says it's invalid. Probably as it is still a draft it is not properly implemented.

Comment: `<form action="index.php" method="post"><input required></form>` validates for me. @DarinDimitrov

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The HTML syntax of the HTML language (which is the one you want to be using, the other one being the XHTML syntax) does allow boolean attributes to be given without a value. So `<div contenteditable>`, `<input required>`, etc. are valid. The important factors are (a) the HTML standard and (b) how browsers implement that standard. If the validator does not conform to these two factors, it's an issue with the validator, not the HTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `data-` attribute is safe and your page will be valid if you use them. But you need qoutation for your value. I'm using data attributes all the time. We support IE7.

```
<input data-required="true">
```

Or even you can leave the value in cases like this:

```
<input data-required>
```

If you are using data attributes often then it's good to know that you can use `dataset` property in Chrome developer tools (and Firebug) to access your element's data attributes via console. It's not safe yet to use `dataset` API in your code. it's not supported in IE8

in your console write:

```
$$('input')[0].dataset
```

and get the data attribute values and properties!

Comment: This worked fine. I just used data-required and checked for its existence. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `required="required"`, it might make older browsers like it better.

***IMPORTANT NOTE: It's still very much valid to write `<input required>`***